# Non-linear least squares with arbitrary number of fitting parameters in R

Tags: r, sum, least-squares, nls

I want to fit a model which includes a sum over a *variable* number of coefficients, such as here

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DG8G.gif)

I would like to write the code so that the number of coefficients can be specified by a potential user when running the fitting routine (i.e. setting *i* to any positive integer value), but I have no idea how to even start coding this. Of course I could simply write out the resulting equations for a large number of potential variables (e.g. for *1 < i < 10*), and switch to the specified one at the beginning, but I would prefer a "prettier" solution (that is fewer lines), if at all available in R. I am currently using *nls*, but of course I would be happy with any solution.

Here's what I tried thus far:

```
Model <- function(X0, t, X, tau){X0+((X*tau*(exp(1/tau)-1))*exp(-t/tau))}

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(t=sort(sample(1:100,50)))
df$P <- jitter(with(df, Model(X0=0.1, t=t, X=0.2, tau=5)), 1000)

Model_fit <- nls(P ~ Model(X0=0.1, t=t, X=X1_fit, tau=5)
                  , start = list(X1_fit=c(0.1)), data=df, trace = F)

plot(df$t,df$P)
lines(df$t, predict(Model_fit, list(P = df$P)))
```

which works just fine. It's also easy to fit more than one coefficient, simply by passing a vector to `X1_fit`. However, what I am now struggling with is how to formulate the sum in the formula correctly. I cannot just use

```
X=c(0.2,5)
Model <- function(X0, t, X, tau){X0+sum((X*tau*(exp(1/tau)-1))*exp(-t/tau))}
```

as this of course returns a single value, i.e. the dependence on `t` gets lost. Instead, the code would need to take the sum only for every individual value of `t`, so that the function still returns a vector of length `t`. However, I am struggling to figure out how to do this without reverting to loops, which might also be difficult to fit via nls?

Cheers!

**Edit**

@G. Grothendieck's answer works fine, but I realised that the fitting procedure is very sensitive to just minor modifications in the equation, in particular when more than just one constant need to be fitted. For example

```
set.seed(1)
Model <- function(X0, t, X, tau) {
  res <- X0 + rowSums(sapply(seq_along(X), function(i) 
(X[i]*tau[i]/5*(exp(5/tau[i])-1))*exp(-t/tau[i])))}

df <- data.frame(t=sort(sample(1:100,50)))
df$P <- jitter(with(df, Model(X0=0.1, t=t, X=c(0.2, 2), tau=c(4, 7))),     1000)

Model_fit <- nls(P ~ Model(X0=0.1, t=t, X=X1_fit, tau=tau_fit)
             , start = list(X1_fit=c(0.1, 1), tau_fit=5:6), data=df)
```

does not run

```
Error in nls(P ~ Model(X0 = 0.1, t = t, X = X1_fit, tau = tau_fit), start = list(X1_fit = c(0.1,  : 
  step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
```

(I added a constant `5` at two places, and now also try to fit `tau`), even when reducing the step-size and increasing the number of iterations. In principle, I appreciate that fitting 4 coefficients is prone to be unstable, but alternative code I have in Matlab seems to deal just fine with it (and even more fitting coefficients, for that matter). Perhaps this would be better in a separate question, but as the thread refers to "arbitrary number of fitting parameters", I feel this follow-up is best done as an edit.

Comment: I added a minimum code example.

Answer (score 1):

`sapply` over i creating a 2d matrix and use `rowSums` to perform the summation:

```
set.seed(1)
Model <- function(X0, t, X, tau) {
  res <- X0 + rowSums(sapply(seq_along(X), function(i) 
     (X[i]*tau[i]*(exp(1/tau[i])-1))*exp(-t/tau[i])))
}

df <- data.frame(t=sort(sample(1:100,50)))
df$P <- jitter(with(df, Model(X0=0.1, t=t, X=c(0.2, 2), tau=c(4, 7))), 1000)



Model_fit <- nls(P ~ Model(X0=0.1, t=t, X=X1_fit, tau=5:6)
                  , start = list(X1_fit=c(0.1, 1)), data=df, trace = F)

plot(df)
lines(fitted(Model_fit) ~ t, df, col = "red")
```

giving:

```
> Model_fit
Nonlinear regression model
  model: P ~ Model(X0 = 0.1, t = t, X = X1_fit, tau = 5:6)
   data: df
X1_fit1 X1_fit2 
 0.2107  2.0849 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.5175

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.511e-07
```

[image: screenshot]